# Cordova - Plugin and config.xml file

Tags: xml, cordova

i try to add the splash screen plugin in the res/xml/config.xml file of my project.

This is what i want:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="fr.myname.firstapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>FirstApp</name>
<description>
    this is my first app
</description>
<author email="email@example.com" href="http://example.com">
    My name
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
...
</widget>
```

After the build of the app with "cordova build android" command, the two lines i added have disappeared:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
```

What can cause that? i don't understand why it override my changes while i just followed official documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config.xml` plugin entries are only for use with the online Phonegap Build system.

If you are building locally, remove the feature tag from `config.xml` and then use the CLI to install the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification
cordova build android
```

Also, for the two lines that you do need in `config.xml`, do not change in `res/xml/config.xml` change in the project root `config.xml` as every time you run the `build` command the platform specific `config.xml` is overwritten with the project level file.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this behavior as well and was pretty confused. For me, this happened when running `ionic cordova run ios` command.

Apparently, this happens when I try to modify `config.xml` file **while this command is running**. Looks like Cordova applies some local modifications to this file during the build, and then rollbacks the version of the file after you end that command. I noticed that whatever changes I make, they are reverted as soon as I press `Ctrl + C` in the command line to end cordova process.

So in my case the solution was to **stop currently running cordova process**, edit `config.xml`, save it and run cordova again. Hope this helps somebody searching for this issue.